# Determining which panel is pressed in, and which one is released in

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, swap

So say I have a Jpanel(container) with 3 Jpanels inside, they are in a JPanel ArrayList. Now I want to be able to determine which Panel the mouse is pressed in, and which one the mouse is released in This way I can reorder the panels in the arraylist, and add them back to the container in the new order.

I have code currently that works for the swap, but the problem is determining which panels are being swapped. I have now an action listener on each other the inner panels that when pressed, startIndex in the container is set to that index, and endIndex is assigned when the mouse is released.

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    con.startIndex = (this);
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    con.endIndex = (this);
    con.swap();
}
```

But it always tries to swap with the same panel that the mouse was pressed in. Anyone have any ideas?

```
public void swap() {
    //This swap code works for the two numbers it's given
    System.out.println("start swapping");
    System.out.println(startSwapIndex + " with " + endSwapIndex);

    if(startSwapIndex != endSwapIndex){
        SpecPanel start = this.getSpecPanel(startSwapIndex);
        SpecPanel end = this.getSpecPanel(endSwapIndex);

        panels.set(endSwapIndex, start);
        panels.set(startSwapIndex, end);

        removeAllSpecPanels();
        addAllSpecPanels();

        System.out.println("swap complete");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is con? what is the code for con.swap()?

Comment: Use a `JList` with draggable elements.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Component c =  container.findComponentAt(event.getX(), event.getY());
```

I think the event coordinates are relative to the panel you clicked on, so you will probably need to convert the coordinates to be relative to the parent panel first. See:

```
SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...);
```

to help you convert the mouse point.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but the mouse listener on the container is never activated, because all the content is above it and is actually clicked on.

Comment: No, you miss my point. I never said anything about a mouse listener on the container. I said you need to convert the mouse point to be relative to the container. Then you can search the container to find the component at that location.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense. I got it working. Thanks a lot for your help